# HTTP Request\Response Header Grammar

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

In the header of an HTTP request or response will the header keys be constant in terms of capitalization, between servers.

I ask so I can expect in my code: (Using Fake Function names)

## Safe Precise Python Code

```
for hdr in header.keys():
    if 'content-length' == hdr.lower():
        recv_more_data( header[hdr] )    # header[hdr] == Content-Length (5388) bytes
        break    # Exit for loop when if statement is met.
```

## Code I Would Like To Use

```
 recv_more_data (header['Content-Length'])    
 # I know to expect 'Content-Length' not 'content-Length' or some other variation
```

Meaning will a server ever return a header with the keys like so.

## Standard Request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example-host.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: closed
Content-Length: 0
```

## A Bad But Possible Response?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.15
date: Thu, 23 Oct 2014 00:25:37 GMT
content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Clarification will help my code neatness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP header names are **case-insensitive**, per the HTTP specification.

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1
[Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2) - Message Headers

> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
> request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
> entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
> that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
> of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. **Field names
> are case-insensitive.** The field value MAY be preceded by any amount
> of LWS, though a single SP is preferred. Header fields can be
> extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at
> least one SP or HT. Applications ought to follow "common form", where
> one is known or indicated, when generating HTTP constructs, since
> there might exist some implementations that fail to accept anything
> beyond the common forms.

[RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing

[Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) - Header Fields:

> Each header field consists of a **case-insensitive field name** followed
> by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and
> optional trailing whitespace.

Comment: Alright very good. I was assuming servers would always handle the case sensitive part. So far must headers i have examined have been such cases. That's why I was curious. Thanks Remy

Comment: Your edit helps even more. I have my header parsing expecting the first colon with a space ': ' not just a colon ':'

Comment: Remy, One more question if you care to answer. When sending requests do you think I should send the 'standard' way or would it be acceptable to send it all lower case? Not according to the the `RFC` but for proper web interaction?

Comment: You should be consistent with what most implementations use, how the RFCs demonstrate them.

Comment: Correct, but there's really no point in mentioning RFC 2616 here.

Comment: The majority of servers implement 2616. 723x was just released a few months ago. I don't know about you, but I had not heard of it until a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that, even though most major servers will have consistent capitalization, any Joe PHP Developer can set the response headers manually in their code - and there is no way to police what that guy uses as a capitalization standard.

Comment: Yes, this was my discomfort. When my code is talking to a "Joe PHP Devolper" written site.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP` header names are case insensitive.

It looks like you're using python. Check out the `requests` library. It'll make your life *much* easier: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Yes. I know the module well. I'm just re-inventing the wheel to get a better grasp of network programming, not application building.