# Can someone explain get requests, specifically the http header?

Tags: python, oauth, get, http-headers, python-requests

I'm new with rest APIs and I'm trying to set up an OAuth handshake and I need help with requesting the request token. I'm using the requests_oauthlib module in Python. Here is the sample code and it is returning Response [400].

consumer_key, consumer_secret, and request_url are all loaded in properly. I got my code to work using a different Auth module. Can someone explain what http headers are and how they are used in a GET request?

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from variables import *

oauth = OAuth1(consumer_key, client_secret = consumer_secret)

request_token = requests.get(request_url, auth=oauth, params={'oauth_callback':'oob', 'format':'json'})

print request_token
```

Answer (score 0):

**request** : your computer sends a http message to another computer usually on port  `443` or `80`

**response** : the server listens for any connection requests, and responds if it understands the message.

For example `telnet stackoverflow.com 80` you can type in

```
GET /questions/52350391/can-someone-explain-get-requests-specifically-the-http-header HTTP/2
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
```

And then press enter twice to conclude the request header, at which point the server responds:

```
➜  mysite telnet stackoverflow.com 80
Trying 151.101.1.69...
Connected to stackoverflow.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /questions/52350391/can-someone-explain-get-requests-specifically-the-http-  header HTTP/2
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350391/can-someone-explain-get-requests-specifically-the-http-
X-Request-Guid: xxx
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
Content-Length: 217
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sun, 16 Sep 2018 03:29:16 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Connection: close
X-Served-By: cache-ord1744-ORD
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1537068557.736123,VS0,VE25
Vary: Fastly-SSL
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Set-Cookie: prov=xxx; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350391/can-someone-explain-get-requests-specifically-the-http-">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The telnet session then prints out the response from the server and closes the connection. The response will include several pieces, the response headers, and the response body.

Your example might look something like:

```
GET /some/oauth/api?oauth_callback=oob&format=json
Host: someplace.com
Authorization: Bearer asdfasdfasdfasdf

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache

{
  "access_token":"sdfasasdfasdf",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"asdfasdfasdfasdf",
  "scope":"create"
}
```

also check out : 
`curl -Lv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350391/can-someone-explain-get-requests-specifically-the-http-header | head -n 100`

related:

- https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/
- [HTTP Request\Response Header Grammer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519400/http-request-response-header-grammer)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers
- https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/authorization/the-authorization-request/